# MassTransit accumulates subscriptions over time

Tags: c#, azure, masstransit

Every time i run my application MassTransit creates a subscription to a topic called `"masstransit.contracts.jobservice~canceljob"` until it reaches 2000 subscriptions (not immediately, they accumulate over time) an stops working.

What i want to know is if this is a "normal" behaviour or if i'm doing something wrong with the configuration, take into account that is just that topic that accumulates subscriptions, the other ones just have 1 or 2 subscriptions so no problem there.

Here is the configuration that i'm using for MassTransit:

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterServiceBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(bus =>
            {
                bus.AddServiceBusMessageScheduler();

                bus.AddConsumers(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
                var busConnnetion = configuration["Bus:Connection"];
                bus.UsingAzureServiceBus(configure: (ctx, cfg) => ConfigureActionCallback(ctx, cfg,             busConnnetion, KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance));
            });

            return services;
        }
```

And the `ConfigureActionCallback` method:

```
static void ConfigureActionCallback(IBusRegistrationContext ctx, IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator cfg, string busConnection, IEndpointNameFormatter enpointNameFormatter)
        {
            cfg.Host(busConnection);

            cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
            cfg.UseMessageRetry(r =>
            {
                r.Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
            });

            cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();

            cfg.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            cfg.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Service Bus has a long standing issue and they are likely never going to fix it. If you create an `AutoDeleteOnIdle` subscription that forwards to another queue, it will *never* get automatically deleted by Azure.

MassTransit handles this by ensuring that all temporary endpoint subscriptions are removed when the bus is stopped (which happens automatically by the .NET Generic Host using MassTransit's hosted service).

If your bus is not properly stopping (you can see the INFO message in the logs at shutdown), those subscriptions will not be forcibly removed by MassTransit. And that results in them accumulating over time because Azure will never respect the `AutoDeleteOnIdle` setting.

So, ensure you bus is stopping when the host is stopped, and monitor topics to ensure subscription counts aren't growing (and maybe setup a regular job to clean out old subscriptions).